# A function whose derivatives always have a convergent fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking for a solid example that such a function that its derivatives can always be found by taking derivatives component-wisely in its Fourier series. A function with finitely many Fourier terms is qualified. But I am looking for a function whose Fourier series contains infinitely many terms. When infinite sum comes into play, the situation becomes more tricky.

I have a candidate, Gaussian $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Is it possible to find a $f$ which is also periodic?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "component-wisely". The components of a Fourier series are constants; you would differentiate the basis functions, and you can always do that (try writing down a "matrix" for $d/dx$ in the orthonormal basis corresponding to sines and cosines).

Comment: @Neal I mean differentiate w.r.t. $x$ componentwisely, and it will induce terms as $2n\pi$, which blow off while n increases.

Comment: So how about a constant function?

Comment: @Neal oh sorry I forgot to mention that the Fourier series should have infinit terms. Already add it in the text. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just an example, here is one: Consider the series
$$s(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1\over 2^k}\>\cos(k\, x)\ .$$
Differentiating termwise we obtain the series
$$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty{k\over 2^k}\>\sin(k\, x)\ .$$
This second series is uniformly convergent on ${\mathbb R}$; therefore its sum is equal to $s'(x)$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$.

In this simple example the given series $s(x)$ can actually be summed explicitly, using $\cos(k\,x)={1\over2}(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$. After simplifying one  obtains
$$s(x)={4-2\cos x\over 5-4\cos x}=:f(x)\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})\ ;$$
therefore the given series is the Fourier series of this $f$.

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks a lot.